# Terminology around consent whilst incapacitated

Tags: legal-terms, consent, sexual-offences

As can be found in numerous places, "consent" is a fairly specific term and has various pre-conditions, such that it cannot be given whilst, for example, *extremely* drunk, under the influence of significantly mind-affecting drugs, or under the legal age of consent *(varies by location)*.

However, there are plenty of scenarios when a person could be in one of those conditions (and thus unable to give consent), but *can* express that they want to have sex.

Such an expression would ***not*** be 'consent', and would ***not*** be grounds for another person to *have* sex with this person. But it feels like a concept that will have come up enough that it might have a formal term to refer to it.

**Is there a term for expressing a desire to have sex whilst not capable of legally consenting?**

Answer (score 2):

As much as possible, you've answered your own question.

"Incapacitated" is the normal word to describe the state were a person's mental faculties are insufficiently reliable for their words or actions to have legal effect.

There is not a legal term to specifically describe the lack of capacity to consent to sex, nor for statements of consent to sex while incapacitated.

Comment: Obviously asking you to cite evidence of the absence of a term would be impossible. Is it safe to assume from your LawSE rep that you're a professional in the legal industry who would be pretty certain to know about such a term if it existed?

Comment: I'd recommend against assuming people with high reputation here are legal professionals; very few of us are. But yes, if such a term were widely used by legal professionals in the United States, I would expect that I would have heard it by now.